# Велики ли возможности литературы?

Tags: литература

Вопросами о границах возможного задаются, как правило, те, кто в своих возможностях ограничен, но не кажется ли вам, что что бы ни создавал сегодня писатель, все созданное будет только вариацией на какую-либо из уже существующих тем? Чем одареннее автор, тем яснее он представляет эстетическое выражение известного сюжета и тем более замысловатые формы имеет его представление. Но одаренность не решает проблему вторичности, а вторичную переработку нельзя назвать искусством. Я не утверждаю, что все идеи уже успели послужить основой для произведений литературного искусства, но не очевидно ли, что не все идеи обладают заслуживающим реализации потенциалом эстетического выражения. Наибольшим обладают уже воспетые в литературе. Обладающие наименьшим вызывают гораздо меньше интереса, но даже их реализация потребует обращения к средствам прежде уже задействованным.

Comment: Так, ну, резюмируя сказанное в ответ, я думаю, можно сказать, что литература продолжит свое существование как искусство вторичной переработки, а ее продукты будут иметь все меньше и меньше ценности.

Answer (score 1):

Жизнь-смерть; любовь-ненависть; добро-зло, верность-измена... Это вечно. Вечные темы - вечные сюжеты. Неудивительно, что произведений с похожими сюжетами много, проверку временем выдержали далеко не все. Так будет и с современной литературой. Через столетия на золотой полке  читателя останется только лучшее. Исключительность, неповторимость стиля, красота формы, языка, особый взгляд на вечную проблему - всё это и сделает произведение бессмертным.

Answer (score 0):

Так "многа букаф", хотя ваша мысль вполне выражается тремя словами: "Всё уже было". Кто-то мудрый сказал: "С вершины все пути ведут вниз". Закат литературы (и вообще искусства) отражает закат цивилизации. Так-то.

Answer (score 0):

То есть вы упёрлись в проблему посмодернизма. Всё уже создано, и осталось только играть со смыслами уже созданного, чтобы порождать новые смыслы, которрые в свою очередь будут порождать материал для новой игры. Так сказать "вторичность, возведённая в образец".

В принципе, нет ничего плохого и в этой игре смыслов. Бориса Акунина или Умберто Эко читать интересно, хотя все их сюжеты это отсылки к другим произведениям. Сомневаюсь я и в вечности постмодернизма, даже рискну предположить, что на смену постмодерну в литературе придёт что-то вроде неоромантизма. А как это всё интерпретировать лично вам, кем видеть себя в мире искусства, решать нужно самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

А вот интересно, можно ли создать такую программу которая бы систематизировала бы все литературные темы, распределили бы но ним все известные сюжеты, да еще бы к разным стилям отнесла.

Берет автор нужную информацию, переставляет по своему вкусу детали или целые модули, а уж потом переводит рисунок-схему в живописное полотно.

Мне бы  такая программа очень подошла, потому что строить значительные объёмы и перспективы я не умею, а раскрашивать частные детали очень люблю.

Что вы скажете по поводу поставленной задачи, уважаемые лингвисты и программисты?

Comment: Марк Из предлагал здесь всем желающим ознакомиться с существующими списками литературных сюжетов, только эти списки не являются руководством по анатомии литературы: начинать ее изучение следует с изучения литературных коллизий. Представить созданное на его основе руководство можно и в форме алгоритма. Начинаться он будет так: конфликт -> ОК, разрешен? -> нет/да -> благополучно ли? -> да/нет...

Comment: Трудно заранее и  с уверенностью сказать, что следует или что не следует делать (человечество движется вперед путем проб и ошибок, находок и открытий). В наше время появились новые информационные возможности, и надо использовать их в полной мере и по всем направлениям. Думаю, что новая наука "анатомия литературы" должна начинаться с накопления описательного материала, сбора фактов (можно, к примеру, для начала провести анкетирование известных произведений по определенной теме). Анализ и исследования - это уже следующий этап.

Comment: С чего бы мы ни начали, я думаю, Ваша мечта о создании схематизирующей программы осуществима и осуществление ее не составит большого труда. Дело в том, что писателю в процессе реализации творческого замысла придется не раз столкнуться с выбором из двух-трех альтернатив. Каким бы боком ни вылез для героя описанный конфликт, прежде всего придется уяснить, выжил ли он, почил ли, или чудесным образом воскрес из мертвых. Героя обидели - герой либо сломался, либо оказал сопротивление. И нет никакой возможности расширить этот выбор.

Comment: Это ужасно, потому что существование такого выбора отнимает у автора инициативу.